# Hpricot, Get all text from document

Tags: html, ruby, hpricot

I have just started learning Ruby.  Very cool language, liking it a lot.

I am using the very handy Hpricot HTML parser.

What I am looking to do is grab all the text from the page, excluding the HTML tags.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Data Protection Checks</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        This is what I want to grab.
        </div>
        <p>
        I also want to grab this text
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am basically wanting to grab only the text so I end up with a string like so:

**"This is what I want to grab. I also want to grab this text"**

What would be the best method of doing this?

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using the XPath `text()` selector.

```
require 'hpricot'
require 'open-uri'

doc  = open("http://stackoverflow.com/") { |f| Hpricot(f) }
text = (doc/"//*/text()") # array of text values
puts text.join("\n")
```

However this is a fair expensive operation. A better solution might be available.

Comment: @Eef, you may need to remove javascript code before collecting the text array `(doc/"script").each {|js| js.inner_html=''}`.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try inner_text.

Like this:

```
h = Hpricot("<html><body><a href='http://yoursite.com?utm=trackmeplease'>http://yoursite.com</a> is <strong>awesome</strong>")
puts h.inner_text
http://yoursite.com is awesome
```

Answer (score 0):

@weppos: This will be bit better:

```
text = doc/"//p|div/text()" # array of text values
```

Comment: yeah, but this assumes he only wants p and div. I think he wants everything.