# Get all text from an XML document?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

How can I get all the text content of an XML document, as a single string - [like this Ruby/hpricot example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243817/hpricot-get-all-text-from-document) but using Python.

I'd like to replace XML tags with a single whitespace.

Comment: The answer you have accepted is wrong, as noted in a comment on it. Would you unaccept it so that a wrong answer is not pinned to the top of the page?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**EDIT:** This is an answer posted when I thought one-space indentation is normal, and as the comments mention it's not a *good* answer. Check out the others for some better solutions. This is left here solely for archival reasons, do **not** follow it!

You asked for lxml:

```
reslist = list(root.iter())
result = ' '.join([element.text for element in reslist])
```

Or:

```
result = ''
for element in root.iter():
    result += element.text + ' '
result = result[:-1] # Remove trailing space
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. It works only if the nodes do not mix child nodes and text content. i.e. it fails for `<node>text <subnode>x</subnode>text2</node>`

Comment: Yes, here is one example that shows what happens if you only take `text` into account and ignore `tail`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12412264/407651

Answer (score 11):

Using stdlib `xml.etree`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('sample.xml') 
print(ET.tostring(tree.getroot(), encoding='utf-8', method='text'))
```

Answer (score 6):

I really like BeautifulSoup, and would rather not use regex on HTML if we can avoid it.

Adapted from: [[this StackOverflow Answer]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2957181/498705), [[BeautifulSoup documentation]](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt)    # txt is simply the a string with your XML file
pageText = soup.findAll(text=True)
print ' '.join(pageText)
```

Though of course, you can (and should) use BeautifulSoup to navigate the page for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that doesn't require an external library like BeautifulSoup, using the built-in sax parsing framework:

```
from xml import sax

class MyHandler(sax.handler.ContentHandler):
    def parse(self, filename):
        self.text = []
        sax.parse(filename, self)
        return ''.join(self.text)

    def characters(self, data):
        self.text.append(data)

result = MyHandler().parse("yourfile.xml")
```

If you need all whitespace intact in the text, also define the `ignorableWhitespace` method in the handler class in the same way `characters` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

This very problem is actually [an example in the lxml tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#using-xpath-to-find-text), which suggests using one of the following XPath expressions to get all the bits of text content from the document as a list of strings:

- `root.xpath("string()")`
- `root.xpath("//text()")`

You'll then want to join these bits of text together into a single big string, with `str.join` probably using `str.strip` to get rid of leading and trailing whitespace on each bit and ignoring bits that are made entirely of whitespace:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> root = etree.fromstring("""
... <node>
...   some text
...   <inner_node someattr="someval">   </inner_node>
...   <inner_node>
...     foo bar
...   </inner_node>
...   yet more text
...   <inner_node />
...   even more text
... </node>
... """)
>>> bits_of_text = root.xpath('//text()')
>>> print(bits_of_text)  # Note that some bits are whitespace-only
['\n  some text\n  ', '   ', '\n  ', '\n    foo bar\n  ', '\n  yet more text\n  ', '\n  even more text\n']
>>> joined_text = ' '.join(
...     bit.strip() for bit in bits_of_text
...     if bit.strip() != ''
... )
>>> print(joined_text)
some text foo bar yet more text even more text
```

Note, by the way, that if you don't want to insert spaces between the bits of text you can just do

```
etree.tostring(root, method='text', encoding='unicode')
```

And if you're dealing with *HTML* instead of *XML*, and are using `lxml.html` to parse your HTML, you can just call the `.text_content()` method of your root node to get all the text it contains (although, again, no spaces will be inserted):

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> root = lxml.html.document_fromstring('<p>stuff<p>more <br><b>stuff</b>bla')
>>> root.text_content()
'stuffmore stuffbla'
```